# how to solve uncaught typeError - cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css

when i ever i click on the burger element nothing happens

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="GNG.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/style.css">
    <title>GnG</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            George n George
        </div>
        <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a> -->
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li class= "nav-active"  ><a href="#">Home </a></li>
            <li ><a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
            <li ><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#">Laundry</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#">Clothes </a></li>
            <li ><a href="#">Business</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="_line1"></div>
            <div class="_line2"></div>
            <div class="_line3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

my css file

```
/*======================== styling the navbaar==========================*/
.burger div{
    width: 25px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin: 5px;
}

.burger{
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    .nav-links{
        width: 40%
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
     body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: rgb(21, 19, 43);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 70%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.9s ease-in;

    }
    .nav-links li{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .burger{
        display: block;
    }
}
.nav-active{
    transform: translateX(0%)
}
 @keyframes _navLinkFade{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px)
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px)
    }
}
/* ======================== navbar end==================================*/
```

and the javascript

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    // const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () =>
    {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) =>
        {
            link.style.animations = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forward ${ index / 7 + 1.5 }s`;


        });
    });
}
navSlide();
```

whenever i click on the burger element, the menu should fade in from the right but looking at the console i see the addEventListener is not working. tried other project with the addeventListner and got same error.  thinking my browser nneeded update wch i did but to no avail

Comment: Your script is imported and evaluated at the top of your HTML source, **before** the DOM has been parsed. Thus those `.querySelector()` calls return `null`.

Comment: will putting it at the bottom of the body solve the problem?

Comment: @Pointy ...thanks, that solved it
but thats where i had it earlier and still had same problem, but its working now, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Move your script tag before closing `</body>` tag or call your function after [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) event;

```
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
  // const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

  burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      link.style.animations = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forward ${index / 7 +
        1.5}s`;
    });
  });
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", navSlide);
```